# Isotope - combining filter by keyword and search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to combine a filter by search and a filter by keyword with Isotope.
For the search filter I based my code on http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu

You can see my code on http://fiddle.jshell.net/8DJ8V/

At the point I'm at now, it works if you start with a search then use filters. But if the user starts using filters, then tries to search, the search won't work.
Probably something wrong in the order I've placed the functions and/or trying to initialize Isotope twice - but I can't get around to it.

Any idea?

Comment: I can't narrow down the issue more that you use 2 different filters and they seem to not work together. I found this script http://charlieperrins.com/isotope-live-search/ where you can filter it with a jquery array, look in the source code for script.js--- I did tried to use isotope relayout in your fiddle, but didnt seem to change anything...

Comment: @Medda86 the author says [it can be done](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/709#issuecomment-43439788) - I've given up and used [Shuffle.js](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The keyup function call the function **$container.isotope()** again and when you click in some button, the filter gets lost.

So I made some changes in your code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/lucaspedroza/7t8mgont/

On line 32, I add the filter function:

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: function() {
      return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : '.active';
    },
  });
}, 200 ) );
```

And clean the input when use the filter so there is no confusion about which filter is being used.

I hope I have help you.

Regards.